Why is my extension running on every webpage despite matches being defined in manifest?
I have a small extension I'm trying to make, it works well for the most part. But the issue is that it can be triggered on every webpage. I only want it to be triggered on the likes page of a post on x.com.
Here is the code from my manifest.json
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Like Searcher",
  "version": "1.0",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting"],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background/background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_icon": {
      "16": "images/icon16.png",
      "48": "images/icon48.png",
      "128": "images/icon128.png"
    }
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://*.x.com/*/status/*/likes"],
      "js": ["background/background.js"]
    }
  ]
}

here is background.js
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (message.action === "executeContentScript") {
    if (message.tabId) {
      chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: message.tabId },
        files: ["content/content.js"],
      });
    } else {
      console.error("Tab ID is missing in the message.");
    }
  }
});

The issue is that the matches seem to do nothing at all. It can be run on every single webpage. Is there something I should be keeping in mind with the matches? I've tried a few different variations on the matches but it never has any effect


It doesn't "run on every page". The action popup can be opened on every page.
Remove content_scripts and background sections from manifest.json, you can't use the same script in both and anyway you don't need them - just use executeScript in your popup script directly. 3) You can get the tab's URL in the popup's script and show the UI accordingly or show a message that the extension doesn't work on this URL. 4) You can change the icon depending on the URL, example.

